# Липкий первый столбец, липкая шапка и горизонтальный скролл в таблице

Tags: css3, html5

Как сделать липкие шапку и первый столбец (полностью первые ячейки в tbody и в thead) таблицы с горизонтальным скроллом? Без ограничений в высоте таблицы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .table-container {
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    tr td, tr th {
      padding: 30px;
    }
    thead {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background-color: darksalmon;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    tbody tr td:first-child {
      position: sticky;
      left: 0;
      background-color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Heading 1</th>
            <th>Heading 2</th>
            <th>Heading 3</th>
            <th>Heading 3</th>
            <th>Heading 4</th>
            <th>Heading 5</th>
            <th>Heading 6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 1.1</td>
            <td>Item 1.2</td>
            <td>Item 1.3</td>
            <td>Item 1.4</td>
            <td>Item 1.5</td>
            <td>Item 1.6</td>
            <td>Item 1.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 2.1</td>
            <td>Item 2.2</td>
            <td>Item 2.3</td>
            <td>Item 2.4</td>
            <td>Item 2.5</td>
            <td>Item 2.6</td>
            <td>Item 2.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 3.1</td>
            <td>Item 3.2</td>
            <td>Item 3.3</td>
            <td>Item 3.4</td>
            <td>Item 3.5</td>
            <td>Item 3.6</td>
            <td>Item 3.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 4.1</td>
            <td>Item 4.2</td>
            <td>Item 4.3</td>
            <td>Item 4.4</td>
            <td>Item 4.5</td>
            <td>Item 4.6</td>
            <td>Item 4.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 5.1</td>
            <td>Item 5.2</td>
            <td>Item 5.3</td>
            <td>Item 5.4</td>
            <td>Item 5.5</td>
            <td>Item 5.6</td>
            <td>Item 5.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 6.1</td>
            <td>Item 6.2</td>
            <td>Item 6.3</td>
            <td>Item 6.4</td>
            <td>Item 6.5</td>
            <td>Item 6.6</td>
            <td>Item 6.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 7.1</td>
            <td>Item 7.2</td>
            <td>Item 7.3</td>
            <td>Item 7.4</td>
            <td>Item 7.5</td>
            <td>Item 7.6</td>
            <td>Item 7.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 8.1</td>
            <td>Item 8.2</td>
            <td>Item 8.3</td>
            <td>Item 8.4</td>
            <td>Item 8.5</td>
            <td>Item 8.6</td>
            <td>Item 8.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 9.1</td>
            <td>Item 9.2</td>
            <td>Item 9.3</td>
            <td>Item 9.4</td>
            <td>Item 9.5</td>
            <td>Item 9.6</td>
            <td>Item 9.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 10.1</td>
            <td>Item 10.2</td>
            <td>Item 10.3</td>
            <td>Item 10.4</td>
            <td>Item 10.5</td>
            <td>Item 10.6</td>
            <td>Item 10.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 11.1</td>
            <td>Item 11.2</td>
            <td>Item 11.3</td>
            <td>Item 11.4</td>
            <td>Item 11.5</td>
            <td>Item 11.6</td>
            <td>Item 11.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 12.1</td>
            <td>Item 12.2</td>
            <td>Item 12.3</td>
            <td>Item 12.4</td>
            <td>Item 12.5</td>
            <td>Item 12.6</td>
            <td>Item 12.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 13.1</td>
            <td>Item 13.2</td>
            <td>Item 13.3</td>
            <td>Item 13.4</td>
            <td>Item 13.5</td>
            <td>Item 13.6</td>
            <td>Item 13.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 14.1</td>
            <td>Item 14.2</td>
            <td>Item 14.3</td>
            <td>Item 14.4</td>
            <td>Item 14.5</td>
            <td>Item 14.6</td>
            <td>Item 14.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 15.1</td>
            <td>Item 15.2</td>
            <td>Item 15.3</td>
            <td>Item 15.4</td>
            <td>Item 15.5</td>
            <td>Item 15.6</td>
            <td>Item 15.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 16.1</td>
            <td>Item 16.2</td>
            <td>Item 16.3</td>
            <td>Item 16.4</td>
            <td>Item 16.5</td>
            <td>Item 16.6</td>
            <td>Item 16.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 17.1</td>
            <td>Item 17.2</td>
            <td>Item 17.3</td>
            <td>Item 17.4</td>
            <td>Item 17.5</td>
            <td>Item 17.6</td>
            <td>Item 17.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 18.1</td>
            <td>Item 18.2</td>
            <td>Item 18.3</td>
            <td>Item 18.4</td>
            <td>Item 18.5</td>
            <td>Item 18.6</td>
            <td>Item 18.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 19.1</td>
            <td>Item 19.2</td>
            <td>Item 19.3</td>
            <td>Item 19.4</td>
            <td>Item 19.5</td>
            <td>Item 19.6</td>
            <td>Item 19.7</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Item 20.1</td>
            <td>Item 20.2</td>
            <td>Item 20.3</td>
            <td>Item 20.4</td>
            <td>Item 20.5</td>
            <td>Item 20.6</td>
            <td>Item 20.7</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что просто задать "липкость" всем первым потомкам в строках будет достаточно:

```css
.table-container {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
tr > * {
  padding: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
tr > *:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: darksalmon;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}
th {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
        <th>Heading 4</th>
        <th>Heading 5</th>
        <th>Heading 6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1.1</td>
        <td>Item 1.2</td>
        <td>Item 1.3</td>
        <td>Item 1.4</td>
        <td>Item 1.5</td>
        <td>Item 1.6</td>
        <td>Item 1.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 2.1</td>
        <td>Item 2.2</td>
        <td>Item 2.3</td>
        <td>Item 2.4</td>
        <td>Item 2.5</td>
        <td>Item 2.6</td>
        <td>Item 2.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 3.1</td>
        <td>Item 3.2</td>
        <td>Item 3.3</td>
        <td>Item 3.4</td>
        <td>Item 3.5</td>
        <td>Item 3.6</td>
        <td>Item 3.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 4.1</td>
        <td>Item 4.2</td>
        <td>Item 4.3</td>
        <td>Item 4.4</td>
        <td>Item 4.5</td>
        <td>Item 4.6</td>
        <td>Item 4.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 5.1</td>
        <td>Item 5.2</td>
        <td>Item 5.3</td>
        <td>Item 5.4</td>
        <td>Item 5.5</td>
        <td>Item 5.6</td>
        <td>Item 5.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 6.1</td>
        <td>Item 6.2</td>
        <td>Item 6.3</td>
        <td>Item 6.4</td>
        <td>Item 6.5</td>
        <td>Item 6.6</td>
        <td>Item 6.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 7.1</td>
        <td>Item 7.2</td>
        <td>Item 7.3</td>
        <td>Item 7.4</td>
        <td>Item 7.5</td>
        <td>Item 7.6</td>
        <td>Item 7.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 8.1</td>
        <td>Item 8.2</td>
        <td>Item 8.3</td>
        <td>Item 8.4</td>
        <td>Item 8.5</td>
        <td>Item 8.6</td>
        <td>Item 8.7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 9.1</td>
        <td>Item 9.2</td>
        <td>Item 9.3</td>
        <td>Item 9.4</td>
        <td>Item 9.5</td>
        <td>Item 9.6</td>
        <td>Item 9.7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```